# Is there a Howard-canon map of Conan's world?

Tags: canon, map, conan

In 1936 "The Hyborian Age: Conan's World", Howard laid out a somewhat detailed "canon" history of Conan's world, pre- and post-cataclysm.

This included verbal description of the world maps and where each people's and states were.

Are there any maps that are Howard canon (either drawn by him, or approved by him as matching the above work's canon description) of both pre- and post- Cataclysm Conan world?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a map of the Hyborian Age drawn by Howard himself.  It clearly shows both the ancient kingdoms and the modern coastlines of the region.  It looks like Howard traced the modern parts, then added his fictional overlay.

[image: Map]

It can be found in *[The Coming of Conan the Cimmerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Coming_of_Conan_the_Cimmerian)*, although it was not published in Howard's lifetime.

Comment: That's one of the worst maps I've ever seen. It's basically a simple map of Europe with some lines scribbled on it, which are barely distinguishable from the background. I'm really puzzled, why he opted for providing a map in this fashion.

Comment: When I opened this answer to read, my Hot Network Questions list's question #1 right next to the answer was Writers.SE "*How to give cartography informations in a fantasy setting without being too precise?*"

Comment: @Dulkan: On the first of your points, Hyborea is imagined to have appeared in Europe's past during a time when sea-levels were lower and thus sketching it over a map of Europe makes sense. On the second of yours points: he didn't. This map was taken from his personal notes and published long after his death. There's no indication he intended to provide this map to readers at all.

Comment: I immediately thought of this: https://www.tor.com/2018/02/15/hippos-worldbuilding-and-amateur-map-making/